# Nginx, PHP-FPM magento configuration gets progressively slower

Tags: magento, nginx, memcached, php

We have a dedicated 2-server setup running magento EE v. 1.10. We are running nginx, php-fpm, memcache as the major modules. The configuration is based on a white paper that magento put out with a hosting company partner.

The server/site gets progressively slower as longer the server is online. After a fresh php-fpm restart, the performance is acceptable. However, as it progresses, time to first byte gets worse and worse. We've had sys admins here and at the hosting company with no solution.  I guess the best way to find help is to ask: Has anyone experienced this problem? We don't believe the issue is related to not having enough server power or memory.

Comment: Try asking at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first place that I would check would be your error logs. Super-sized logs combined with unaddressed (and therefore continually logged) errors can lead to significant load time increases.

Comment: it may be a memory leak. Res memory for a php-fpm process starts at 30mb when we start php-fpm. Each process after continues to grow. We left it overnight and each php-fpm process was at 1.1GB res memory. Would that be a memory leak?